# CSS - row com col-md-6 que contém fotos não está alinhada corretamente

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho uma listagem de 8 fotografias e depois tenho um botão que me carrega mais duas fotografias. No entanto, as fotografias não aparecem alinhadas corretamente pois aparece sempre um buraco sem nenhuma fotografia.

[image: Captura de imagem da listagem de fotografias]

O código que tenho é o seguinte:

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1 text-center">
                <h2>Portfolio</h2>
                <hr class="small">
                <div class="row">
                <?php
            $query=mysqli_query($db,"select id_album, nome, foto from albuns order by id_album ASC limit 8");
             while($cat=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){?>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                        <p class="imgDescription"> <?php echo $cat['nome'];?> </p>
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="<?php echo $cat['foto'];?>" onClick="location.href='listagem_album.php?id=<?php echo $cat['id_album'];?>'">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>

             <?php
            $query=mysqli_query($db,"select id_album, nome, foto from albuns order by id_album DESC limit 2");
             while($cat=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){?>
                    <div class="col-md-6" id="fotos" >
                        <div class="portfolio-item">
                        <p class="imgDescription"> <?php echo $cat['nome'];?> </p>
                            <a href="#">
                                <img class="img-portfolio img-responsive" src="<?php echo $cat['foto'];?>" onClick="location.href='listagem_album.php?id=<?php echo $cat['id_album'];?>'">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                   <?php } ?>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row (nested) -->
                 <div id="button" style=" width: 150px;height: 75px;"><a class="btn btn-dark" style="margin-left: 400px;
margin-top: 0px;">View More Items</a></div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-10 -->
        </div>
```

Comment: Tente fazer com que cada linha (`.col-md-6`) tenha uma altura (`height`) sempre igual, pode fazer isso facilmente nos seus css. A razão para isso acontecer é que as fotos  têm alturas diferentes e a altura de cada linha (as duas fotos lado a lado) ajusta-se sempre consoante a foto maior. Creio que ficará resolvido se puser uma altura fixa

Comment: É isso mesmo @Miguel. Acrescento também Claudia, que você crie uma div col-md-12 com cada imagem ocupando col-md-6 dentro dessa, assim as próximas duas abaixo independerão das de cima.